# Do you think this question should be put on hold, when this other question isn't? And if so, how would I improve it?

Tags: discussion

Do you think [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/267072/what-is-the-most-concise-way-to-describe-these-strange-wings) should be put on hold, when [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257216/is-there-a-more-concise-way-to-describe-this-hairstyle), question hasn't been?

If you do, how would you improve it so it's good enough to open?

Is it just that the former question is "What's the best way to . . . ?", while the latter is "Is there a more concise way to..."?

If you think so, then I'll change them to match, and the best answer would be judged on a 50-50 basis around how accurate the description is, and how wordy it is.

Comment: If you find another question you think should be closed, then flag it!

Comment: @curiousdannii - What? I'm asking how to improve my own questions... What are you talking about?

Comment: Heh, sorry I didn't notice they were both yours. It's very common for people to complain that their question was closed when another similar question wasn't (or at least compare them as if that should mean the closed question shouldn't be closed), and I assumed that's what this was.

Comment: I don't find either question appropriate for the site, sorry. --- I don't know why, but I don't seem to be able to edit the question.  My edit would have been to change the title to "Do you think this question should be put on hold, when this other question isn't? And if so, how would I improve it?

Answer (score 4):

My feeling is that those questions cannot have a single “right” answer, only an open set of countless possibilities offered up based on diverse personal opinion.  This also makes it hard to judge which one to choose.

It is true that one can find many examples of other such open-ended questions here, but I don’t think they’re a very good fit for a question-and-answer site.

I may be wrong, however.

Comment: I agree: questions of the form "Is there a more concise way to describe X?" are not only opinion-based but requests for writing advice.  However, a question of the form "Is there an term for X in English?" would be on-topic; and I have no doubt that Joe Blow's answer to the [second question](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/257222/24489) as if it were in that form contributed to keeping the question open.

Comment: @StoneyB - Changed that 1st question. Gonna reword the second... Err... Disregard that last point... That would alter the question too much.